# node.js/ Getting buffer on data.socket

Tags: node.js

I use node.js, and have the next code:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
socket.on('data', function(d) {
console.log(d);}}
```

I see that it prints the next:

```
<Buffer 47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0..>
```

Even if I open a conection in my localhost. What can be the reason? How I change it that it would get the http request?

Comment: If you want the HTTP *request*, you should use [`http.createServer`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener).

Answer (score 10):

According to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data), you must specify the encoding with the `setEncoding()` method to receive an string.
If you don't, you'll receive an Buffer with raw data because Node will not know what encoding you want - and Node deals with very low level networking.

For example:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.setEncoding("utf8");
  socket.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d); // will be string
  }
}
```

If you don't want to, you can always call `toString()`:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Or use `d.toString()` as an alternative.